# can someone help me with this (most likely simple) error?

Tags: c#

I have just started to learn coding and was hoping someone with a little more skill would help me out a bit.

Here is the code and when i run it the displayarray is coming up as just zeros and then the sum of the array is also zero I just cant grasp why thats happening so it would be awesome if someone could help me out.

```
namespace random_array_2._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array;

            int sum = 0;

            int arraySum;
           

            array = CreateArray();

            DisplayArray(array);

            arraySum = SumTheArray(array, sum);

        }

        static int[] CreateArray()
        {
            
            Random Array = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Array.Next(1, 100));  
            }
            return new int[10]; 
        }

        static void DisplayArray(int[] array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Sorted array in ASC order");
            Array.Sort(array);
            foreach (int i in array)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
            }
        }

        static int SumTheArray (int[] array, int sum)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += array[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"all together equals to: {sum}");

            Console.ReadKey();

            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I would strongly advise you to use a known good guide/tutorial to learn the language. Just trial-and-erroring it is not a good way to properly learn a language. You need guidance if only not to learn bad habits.

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: OT you don't need to pass that `sum` parameter into `SumTheArray` as it is not a useful input - just make it a local variable (and still return it)

Comment: What kind of results did you see when you ran your debugger and stepped through your code?

Answer (score 3):

Your `CreateArray` function is printing 10 random numbers and then returning a new array. The default value for `int` is 0, so this array contains 10 zeros.
You should first create the array and then populate it with random values:

```
static int[] CreateArray()
    {
        
        Random Array = new Random();
        var a = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) 
        {
            a[i] = Array.Next(1, 100);  
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
static int[] CreateArray()
{
    
    Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
    int[] array = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
    {
        int randomNumber = randomNumberGenerator.Next(1, 100);
        array[i] = randomNumber;
    }
    return array; 
}
```

My advise to you is to stop using `Console.WriteLine` statements and start using the debugger.  `Console.WriteLine` often lies; the debugger tends to never lie.

Answer (score 1):

Your CreateArray function is not storing anything into Array, and it's returning an array with 10 zeroes (default value when none in given).

Try with

```
static int[] CreateArray()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int[] Array = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        Array[i] = rnd.Next(1, 100);
    }
    return Array;
}
```